# SQL Date selection based on redord status

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I Have test master table with ID and name

```
TestMaster          
ID  Name        
1   a       
2   b       
3   c
```

and testtrans have ID master id, start and end date

```
TestTrans           
ID  MasterID    Statusdate  Outcome
1   1   01/01/2013  Close
2   1   03/01/2013  Open
3   1   06/01/2013  Open
4   1   10/01/2013  Close
5   1   12/01/2013  Open
6   2   10/10/2012  Open
7   2   15/10/2012  Close
8   2   15/10/2012  Open
9   3   15/01/2013  Open
10  3   20/01/2013  Close
11   3  21/01/2013  Open
12  3        25/01/2013         Open
```

I need output like this
start date: should be statusdate of the record
end date: should be based on the record status. if the status is closed then end date is closed record's satatusdate, all the records prior to closed staus will be deemed to be part of same group

group by Masetr ID

```
Output          
Master ID   Start date  end date    
1   01/01/2013  01/01/2013  
1   03/01/2013  10/01/2013  
1   12/01/2013  NULL    
2   10/10/2012  15/10/2012  
2   15/10/2012  Null    
3   15/01/2013  20/01/2013  
3    21/01/2013        Null
```

Comment: Sorry but you need some punctuation here, I can't be sure what you're saying "end date should be based on the record status if the status is closed then end date is closed record's satatusdate all record prior to closed staus will be deemed to be part of same group" i.e. What's the difference between "Lets eat Grandma!" and "Lets eat, Grandma!"

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
      ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
    , MasterID INT
    , StatusDate datetime
    , Outcome VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @temp (MasterID, StatusDate, Outcome)
VALUES 
    (1,   '20130101',  'Close'),
    (1,   '20130103',  'Open'),
    (1,   '20130106',  'Open'),
    (1,   '20130110',  'Close'),
    (1,   '20130112',  'Open'),
    (2,   '20121010',  'Open'),
    (2,   '20121015',  'Close'),
    (2,   '20121015',  'Open'),
    (3,   '20130115',  'Open'),
    (3,   '20130120',  'Close'),
    (3,   '20130121',  'Open'), 
    (3,   '20130125',  'Open')

;WITH data AS 
(
    SELECT 
          t.MasterId
        , StartDate = t.StatusDate
        , EndDate = t.StatusDate
    FROM @temp t
    WHERE OutCome = 'Close'
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM @temp t2
            WHERE t.StatusDate > t2.StatusDate
                AND t.MasterID = t2.MasterID
                AND t2.OutCome = 'Open'
        )

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
          MasterId
        , StartDate = t.StatusDate
        , a.EndDate 
    FROM @temp t
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT EndDate = MAX(StatusDate) 
        FROM @temp a 
        WHERE a.MasterId = t.MasterId
            AND a.Outcome = 'Close'
            AND a.StatusDate > t.StatusDate
    ) a
    WHERE OutCome = 'Open'
        AND (
                NOT EXISTS(
                    SELECT 1 
                    FROM @temp t2
                    WHERE t.StatusDate > t2.StatusDate
                        AND t.MasterID = t2.MasterID
                        AND t.Outcome = t2.Outcome
                ) 
            OR 
                a.EndDate IS NULL
            )
)
SELECT *
FROM data d
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM data d2 
    WHERE d.MasterID = d2.MasterID
        AND d.StartDate > d2.StartDate
        AND d.EndDate IS NULL
        AND d2.EndDate IS NULL
)
ORDER BY 
      d.MasterID
    , d.StartDate
    , d.EndDate
```

Comment: The above works fine but If I Add two more records like    (3,   '20130121',  'Open'),
    (3,   '20130125',  'Open')                                   the output shows                                                   MasterId StartDate                       EndDate
3 2013-01-15 00:00:00.000 2013-01-20 00:00:00.000
3 2013-01-21 00:00:00.000 NULL
3 2013-01-25 00:00:00.000 NULL but the last record shoul not shown because the record status is still open for the group. Please help

Comment: Could you please let me know why the provided solution didn't suit you?